# Stream delete events from MySQL to PostgreSQL via Apache-kafka

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka, mysql-connector

I am trying to stream events from `MySQL` to `PostgreSQL` using `Apache Kafka.` Although insertions and updates work fine, I can't figure out how to delete a record from `MySQL` and stream this event to `PostgreSQL`.

Assume the following topology:

```
               +-------------+
               |             |
               |    MySQL    |
               |             |
               +------+------+
                      |
                      |
                      |
      +---------------v------------------+
      |                                  |
      |           Kafka Connect          |
      |  (Debezium, JDBC connectors)     |
      |                                  |
      +---------------+------------------+
                      |
                      |
                      |
                      |
              +-------v--------+
              |                |
              |   PostgreSQL   |
              |                |
              +----------------+
```

I am using the following docker images;

1. [Apache-Zookeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/zookeeper/)
2. [Apache-Kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/kafka/)
3. [Debezium/JDBC connectors](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect/)

Then

```
# Start the application
export DEBEZIUM_VERSION=0.6
docker-compose up

# Start PostgreSQL connector
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @jdbc-sink.json

# Start MySQL connector
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @source.json
```

Here is the content of MySQL database;

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml exec mysql bash -c 'mysql -u $MYSQL_USER  -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD inventory -e "select * from customers"'
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| id   | first_name | last_name | email                 |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 1001 | Sally      | Thomas    | sally.thomas@acme.com |
| 1002 | George     | Bailey    | gbailey@foobar.com    |
| 1003 | Edward     | Walker    | ed@walker.com         |
| 1004 | Anne       | Kretchmar | annek@noanswer.org    |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

And we can verify that the content of PostgresSQL is identical;

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml exec postgres bash -c 'psql -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB -c "select * from customers"'
 last_name |  id  | first_name |         email         
-----------+------+------------+-----------------------
 Thomas    | 1001 | Sally      | sally.thomas@acme.com
 Bailey    | 1002 | George     | gbailey@foobar.com
 Walker    | 1003 | Edward     | ed@walker.com
 Kretchmar | 1004 | Anne       | annek@noanswer.org
(4 rows)
```

Assume that I want to delete the record with `id=1004` from MySQL database;

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml exec mysql bash -c 'mysql -u $MYSQL_USER  -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD inventory'
mysql> delete from customers where id = 1004;


docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml exec mysql bash -c 'mysql -u $MYSQL_USER  -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD inventory -e "select * from customers"'
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| id   | first_name | last_name | email                 |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 1001 | Sally      | Thomas    | sally.thomas@acme.com |
| 1002 | George     | Bailey    | gbailey@foobar.com    |
| 1003 | Edward     | Walker    | ed@walker.com         |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Although the record is deleted from MySQL, the entry still appears in PostgresSQL

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-jdbc.yaml exec postgres bash -c 'psql -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB -c "select * from customers"'

 last_name |  id  | first_name |         email         
-----------+------+------------+-----------------------
 Thomas    | 1001 | Sally      | sally.thomas@acme.com
 Bailey    | 1002 | George     | gbailey@foobar.com
 Walker    | 1003 | Edward     | ed@walker.com
 Kretchmar | 1004 | Anne       | annek@noanswer.org
(4 rows)
```

I understand that soft deletes are supported however, is it possible to completely delete that particular entry from `PostgresSQL` as well (by streaming the del event from MySQL via Apache-Kafka)?

**EDIT:**

This is the content of `source.json` file

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "debezium",
        "database.password": "dbz",
        "database.server.id": "184054",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "database.whitelist": "inventory",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "transforms": "route",
        "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
    }
}
```

Here is the content of `jdbc-sink.json` file

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "customers",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/inventory?user=postgresuser&password=postgrespw",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

I have also tried to set `"pk.mode": "record_key"` and `"delete.enabled": "true"` ([bug fix suggestion](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/282)) but this modification doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Deletes are currently not supported by the Confluent JDBC sink connector. There's a pending pull request (you already linked to it), but this hasn't been merged yet.

For the time being, you could either build the JDBC sink connector based on that branch yourself, or you create a simple custom sink connector which just handles tombstone events by executing a corresponding DELETE statement on the target database.