# Kafka can not stream database activity

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, debezium

I'm streaming my PostgreSQL using confluent (./kafka-avro-console-consumer). Successfully streaming, but Kafka only showed INSERT activity. Other than that like DELETE, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, didn't stream on my Kafka consume.

I did:

- Install PostgreSQL including making role until making tables
- Install debezium CDC for PostgreSQL (I didn't use json/jdbc at all)
- Install wal2json
- Making connector to confluent
- Automatically: topics are made after successfully deploy the connector
- Stream topics ./kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic debezium.public.emp_bio --from-beginning

This is my connector

```
{
 "name": "postgres-connector-1",
 "config": {
 "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "database.hostname": "localhost",
 "database.port": "5432",
 "database.user": "dbuser1",
 "database.password": "password",
 "database.dbname":"testdb",
 "database.server.name": "debezium",
 "database.whitelist": "testdb",
 "plugin.name": "wal2json",
 "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
 "database.history.kafka.topic": "postgres-hist-test",
 "include.schema.changes": "true"
 }
}
```

Expected: I can stream other activities like DELETE, DROP, UPDATE, CREATE from my PostgreSQL
Error: Sorry, there is no error message anywhere!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream delete events from MySQL to PostgreSQL via Apache-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866065/stream-delete-events-from-mysql-to-postgresql-via-apache-kafka)

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous it's different. I use CDC when that question using JDBC. Obviously used json when I didn't.

Comment: Could you please try setting `REPLICA IDENTITY` for table(s) to `FULL`? https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#replica-identity
Also do you see `INSERT` even during streaming not only during snapshot?
Also please bear in mind that you'll see only DML not DDL commands so there will be no `CREATE/DROP TABLE` etc.